# Applicability of Reflection

Tags: .net, reflection

There are some great articles out there such as [**this one**](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Reflection.aspx) on Reflection.

What I want to know is real world examples where it is used and real world reasons or when it's useful and why outside the raw "you can get type info"...I get all that in this article and others.

Ok, so what, it doesn't really help me in context to actual programming situations.  I'm trying to figure out how people are using it in apps, good examples of times that they have been used just to get my head wrapped around when you'd want to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reflection is useful for run-time plugins. When you make a program that can be extended via plugins, by definition you don't know what the classes and methods are at compile-time, so you use reflection to load the libraries at run-time and then call the appropriate methods.

Comment: I'm confused.  So if you don't know what the classes and methods are at compile time, then your code at compile time is meant to take in any type at runtime as long as it meets x criteria/requirements for that method to function at runtime?

Comment: Well, what you do is define a standard `interface`. Then you provide code that uses the interface; then at run-time, you load an actual class that implements the interface, instantiate it, and pass the object around to your methods that accepted the interface.
Hope that made sense? :)

Comment: @CoffeAddict: If you require plugin classes to implement a certain interface, you don't need reflection to call classes, you can just invoke them as regular methods. You still need reflection to load and possibly instantiate the plugin class in the first place, and that can only happen by the name of the class, which must be supplied as a run-time parameter. That's how e.g. JDBC works.

Answer (score 1):

Reflection is also useful when you are dealing with serialization.

Just recently I had to write some very custom serialization code for talking to a third party service, this meant using reflection to find properties, and determine whether the property was eligible to be serialized depending on the attribute.

Comment: yea isn't it used as a way to transform xml?

Answer (score 1):

A good real-life example of reflection is [Spring's Inversion of Control (IoC) framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html) in Java where you can wire your beans using XML configurations.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Mehrdad, run-time plugins are one are where reflection is used. A good example is the JDBC API. You use reflection to load the driver class by name; that's the only way to do it, as the JVM cannot know which class to load on its own.

Another situation where reflection is useful is for application frameworks that are supposed to run arbitrary code. Examples:

- application servers
- unit testing frameworks (JUnit uses reflection extensively)
- RPC-type applications (e.g. XML-RPC)

Yet another is persistence frameworks, which can load/save arbitrary class instances (e.g. Hibernate).